# What is a PCB stencil with framework?

Tags: pcb, stencil

I am ordering a PCB stencil from a manufacturer and there is an option for stencil framework.  What does this mean, and should I include it?  By default it is selected as no on the manufacturer's checkout process.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a stencil printer?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I do not.  Just a reflow oven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a stencil printer (or intend to get one) like this one: (photo from aliexpress)

[image]

.. the stencil frame will be clamped by the four screws in the U-channel.

[image]

Usually they will put both sides of the PCB on one stencil by default, for a smaller board or panel.

If you are just going to do one or two by hand without a printer (for example, by taping down the stencil), the frame is not necessary, and may get in the way if you don't have an appropriate way of mounting the stencil.

DIY stencil shown here (photo from [here](https://rayshobby.net/wordpress/learning-to-make-solder-paste-stencils/):

[image]

The frame is not much more expensive in China, but the shipping cost will increase noticeably.